# Auto-relacionamento no mysql

Tags: mysql, chave-estrangeira

Estou tentando implementar uma tabela no MYSQL com auto relacionamento, é uma tabela de cadastro funcionários, na qual o funcionáro  administrador´(F.A) cadastra o funcionário comum (F.C) Seria registrada na tupla do F.C qual F.A o registrou, eu criei o campo **codfunc** como chave primaria e chave estrangeira nesta tabela para criar o auto relacionamento, se o perfil for 1 ele é FA, portanto ele se auto registra, se for perfil 2 é Funcionário comum e então ele recebe  o código do funcionário que o registrou.   por ex:

CODFUNC  nome   perfil        codfunc(F.K)

```
1      Jose   1(F.A)      Null

2      João   2(F.C)       1
```

Só que não consigo fazer nenhum insert do jeito que fiz. Como poderia criar um auto relacionamento?

Comment: você está usando pdo, mysqli ? como você está fazendo o código!

Comment: Eu só estou implementando o banco por enquanto no workbench

Comment: @Mrbobot ,posta o código do seu CREATE TABLE e dos INSERTS, para gente conseguir ver o que pode ser melhorado.

Comment: Como você está fazendo o `insert`?

Comment: @MarcusVinicius                                                                                         CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`FUNC` (
  `CODFUNC` VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  `NOME` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `PERFIL` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
  `CPF` BIGINT(16) NOT NULL,
  `codfunc1` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CODFUNC`),
  INDEX `codfunc_idx` (`codfunc1` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `codfunc`
    FOREIGN KEY (`codfunc1`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`FUNC` (`CODFUNC`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8;

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, tentei inserir o F.A :                                                              (1, José ,1 , null)  mas nao deu certo

Comment: Então, está fazendo a tabela errado, deveria o codfunc ser int e o seu respectivo tambem, perfil não precisa já visto que se o código respectivo for nulo é o pai de todos. Bom eu faria totalmente diferente do que está ai!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mydb.FUNC ( 
    CODFUNC VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL, 
    NOME VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL, 
    PERFIL TINYINT(4) NOT NULL, 
    CPF BIGINT(16) NOT NULL, 
    codfunc1 VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (CODFUNC), 
    INDEX codfunc_idx (codfunc1 ASC), 
    CONSTRAINT codfunc 
        FOREIGN KEY (codfunc1) 
        REFERENCES mydb.FUNC (CODFUNC) 
        ON DELETE NO ACTION 
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION) 
    ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT 
    CHARACTER SET = utf8;

    INSERT INTO FUNC(CODFUNC,NOME,PERFIL,CPF,CODFUNC1) VALUES ("1","BATMAN",1,1234567899,"1");

    INSERT INTO FUNC(CODFUNC,NOME,PERFIL,CPF,CODFUNC1) VALUES ("2","LANTERNA VERDE",2,0987654321,"1");

    INSERT INTO FUNC(CODFUNC,NOME,PERFIL,CPF,CODFUNC1) VALUES ("3","AQUAMAN",2,343423433,"2");

    SELECT * FROM FUNC;
```

---

Eu consegui realizar os INSERT a cima normalmente, confere e vê se é o que você está precisando. Só uma duvida, o CODFUNC de um funcionário vai mesmo ter letras e números?.

Comment: deu certo do jeito que vc fez, obrigado. Eu estava fazendo o insert direto sem especificar os campos e não estava aceitando.